# Microcontroller mosfet switch

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, switches, switch-mode-power-supply, pmos

There are three different processors in my circuit. These are STM32F401RCT6, ATmega328P and ESP32. I want to turn these processors on and off with the switch whenever I want. The circuit I created for this is available below. In this circuit, if the switch is in transmission, I want ATmega and STM to be in transmission. Is it possible with this circuit?

[image]

Comment: By "in transmission" do you just mean "powered on?"

Comment: Yes, when the button is on, the P channel mosfet is activated.
 If it is N chanell mosfet, I want it to be blocked

Comment: @EmreCelik Can you ask a specific question?

Comment: The signals going to the P-channel MOSFET gates need to be switched to GND, not 5V. Should also change those series gate resistors into pullup resistors from gate to source. 100K should work.

Comment: @Ste Kulov - you are right, but be aware, that it lasts ca. 400 us until the power is switched off completely due to the high Gate-Source capacitance - see the [datasheet of the P channel MOSFET](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IRLML6401-DataSheet-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535668b96d2634). During this time the processors are operated with a voltage between 0 and 3.3/5V - is this allowed? Disturbing them?

Comment: @BitLauncher Good point. It’s up to the designer if that’s an issue and select pullup resistor and/or additional reset supervisor circuitry accordingly.